# Unable to install Hardhat waffle on Apple Silicon

Tags: ethereum, hardhat

I am working on my first ever DAPP following a tutorial:

The following command is given for to install the hardhat-waffle on to the device using npm:

```
npm install --save-dev @nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle 'ethereum-waffle@^3.0.0' @nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers 'ethers@^5.0.0'
```

on running this command I am getting:

```
npm WARN deprecated ganache-core@2.13.2: ganache-core is now ganache; visit https://trfl.io/g7 for details
npm WARN deprecated ganache-core@2.13.2: ganache-core is now ganache; visit https://trfl.io/g7 for details
npm WARN deprecated testrpc@0.0.1: testrpc has been renamed to ganache-cli, please use this package from now on.
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN deprecated @ensdomains/ens@0.4.5: Please use @ensdomains/ens-contracts
npm WARN deprecated @ensdomains/resolver@0.2.4: Please use @ensdomains/ens-contracts
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/phoenix_20/Desktop/Web3.0/smart_contract/node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/bufferutil
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c -- node-gyp-build
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.1.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@18.4.0 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.9.13 found at "/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9"
npm ERR! gyp info spawn /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/phoenix_20/.nvm/versions/node/v18.4.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/phoenix_20/Desktop/Web3.0/smart_contract/node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/bufferutil/build/config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/phoenix_20/.nvm/versions/node/v18.4.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/phoenix_20/Library/Caches/node-gyp/18.4.0/include/node/common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/phoenix_20/Library/Caches/node-gyp/18.4.0',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/Users/phoenix_20/.nvm/versions/node/v18.4.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/phoenix_20/Library/Caches/node-gyp/18.4.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/phoenix_20/Desktop/Web3.0/smart_contract/node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/bufferutil',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
```

PS : I have tried bunch of solution none work and I am also new to Web3.0

I am expecting this package to get install without any error.

Answer (score 0):

Add / replace this block of code inside of `package.json` file:

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox": "^2.0.0",
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers": "^2.2.1",
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle": "^2.0.3",
    "chai": "^4.3.7",
    "ethereum-waffle": "^3.4.4",
    "ethers": "^5.7.2",
    "hardhat": "^2.12.4"
}
```

It may solve the problem!

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow these steps to solve these problem

1. run the below command.

```
npm install -D hardhat @nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers ethers @nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle ethereum-waffle chai
```

2. check your `package.json` file

```
{
  "name": "smart_contracts",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers": "^2.2.3",
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle": "^2.0.6",
    "chai": "^4.3.7",
    "ethereum-waffle": "^3.4.4",
    "ethers": "^5.7.2",
    "hardhat": "^2.16.1"
  }
}
```

check the dependencies are installed properly or not

3. run the hardhat check your testnet in my case it is `goerli`

```
npx hardhat run scripts/deploy.js --network goerli
```

[image: After succesful it shows like these]

After succesful it shows like these

`thank you`